# as.Date character string with month-day data

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

Hi I am trying to determine whether my data points occurred during a proposed work season. I have this function:

```
### Get whether or not sighting occurred during the proposed work period
getWork <-function(w) {
    startWork <- as.Date("07-15", format = "%m-%d") #Start of stated work period
    endWork <- as.Date("02-15", format = "%m-%d") #End of stated work period

  ifelse (w >=startWork & w <= endWork, 1, 0)
  }

#convert SightDate to Month-Day
sightingsData$SightMonthDay <- format(sightingsData$SightDate, format="%m-%d")
sightingsData$workPeriod <- getWork(sightingsData$SightMonthDay) #Get Work T/F values for each date
```

The code for the function runs smoothly without errors, but I get an error for the output, as follows:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format 
6. stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format") 
5. charToDate(x) 
4. as.Date.character(e1) 
3. as.Date(e1) 
2. `>=.Date`(w, startWork) 
1. getWork(sightingsData$SightMonthDay)
```

However, if I change the syntax of the function to match that of creating the 'SightMonthDay' column, `(i.e. startwork <- as.Date.... instead of startwork <- format....)`I get an output, but all of the 'getWork' values are apparently between -1 and 0, however all of the observations are considered 0 [False] which out of over 23500 observations is not true. Here is the code to illustrate what I mean:

```
getWork <-function(w) {
    startWork <- format("07-15", format = "%m-%d") #Start of stated work period
    endWork <- format("02-15", format = "%m-%d") #End of stated work period
    +(w >=startWork & w <= endWork)
}

#convert SightDate to Month-Day
sightingsData$SightMonthDay <- format(sightingsData$SightDate, format="%m-%d")
sightingsData$workPeriod <- getWork(sightingsData$SightMonthDay) #Get Work T/F values for each date
```

And here's a little screenshot to show what I mean...

[image]

Here's a sample dataset:

```
       SightDate SightMonthDay workPeriod
18163 2017-11-15         11-15          0
17120 2017-10-23         10-23          0

> dput(droplevels(SampleData[1:20, ]))
structure(list(SightDate = structure(c(17485, 17462, 17469, 17417, 
17871, 17294, 16712, 15069, 16576, 17416, 17515, 16407, 16399, 
17298, 17164, 17244, 17464, 15628, 16388, 16598), class = "Date"), 
    SightMonthDay = c("11-15", "10-23", "10-30", "09-08", "12-06", 
    "05-08", "10-04", "04-05", "05-21", "09-07", "12-15", "12-03", 
    "11-25", "05-12", "12-29", "03-19", "10-25", "10-15", "11-14", 
    "06-12"), workPeriod = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(18163L, 
17120L, 17437L, 15597L, 23402L, 14359L, 9874L, 2902L, 8910L, 
15585L, 19641L, 7769L, 7631L, 14399L, 13163L, 13447L, 17297L, 
4511L, 7405L, 9113L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your time and help!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your `startWork` and `endWork` are replaced.

```
getWork <-function(w) {
   endWork <- as.Date("07-15", format = "%m-%d") #Start of stated work period
   startWork <- as.Date("02-15", format = "%m-%d") #End of stated work period
   +(w >=startWork & w <= endWork)
}
```

and apply it to `SightMonthDay`.

```
SampleData$new_date <- as.Date(format(SampleData$SightDate, "%m-%d"), "%m-%d")
getWork(SampleData$new_date)

#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks! However, that didn't work for me at least not with the SightMonthDay data formatting. I've updated my post to show where I'm at now after I've included your feedback. Thanks for all your time and help!!

Comment: @SalmaAbdel-Raheem You need to get dates in the same year. See updated answer.